# php string to insret emoji in database

Tags: php, mysql, utf8mb4

I converted a forum MySQL database to utf8mb4.
Seems to be working fine as Emojis are saving and displaying fine.

But I am having issues with a chatbox.
emojis are saved in the database as Unicode `"%uD83D%uDE0B"`

Works fine if emojis is inserted by phpmyadmin.

Can this be solved by `mb_convert` or something ?

php 5.6

Could this be the problematic code-

```
$str = unhtmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\n"), '', trim(convert_urlencoded_unicode($str))));
```

With code ☀️ 3 byte emoji works,  do not.
with code commented // hex for both.

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch UTF-16.  Use only UTF-8.  In MySQL, UTF-8 is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

is hex `D83DDE0B` in UTF-16, but you need hex `F09F988B` in utf8mb4.

Perhaps the data is being created by Java or some other source?

There is virtually no reason to every us a conversion routine in PHP.

Comment: DB is utf8mb4 with collation utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci, its php and MySql only. I have update the question.

Comment: Do not use any conversion routines in PHP -- they are likely to make things _worse_.  Provide the bin2hex() before and after your `$str=` code.